# find cursor exceed the actual size of the collection - Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, cursor

I looked for answers a lot before asking, but it looks like no one had that problem before it's quite weird though

I have a mongo collection of `size ~ 175000000` 
this is what i got from `db.collection.find().count()`

but when i run the iterator in java driver,

```
  while(cursor.hasNext()) { 
    System.out.println("Document Number "+docnumber); 
    docnumber++; 
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
  }
```

it reaches `~ 279000000` !! so approx 100million extra docs! 
where did that come from.

I had that problem with another collection with 43 million documents.. 
and after running it several time it worked and stopped at the right end of collection.

Comment: Is there any other access to this collection? Have you got a sharded setup? What MongoDB version? It is very hard to be able to debug this without seeing it and your setup

Comment: @Sammaye it's version 2.6 , I am the only person who access this collection

Comment: What's the output of `db.collection.stats()` in the mongo console?

Comment: @mnemosyn the count in stats is the correct one (175809426)

Comment: @mnemosyn also cursor.size() in java is 175809426. Only when i do the for loop like above.. it exceeds

Comment: Can you give us a raw output of db.collection.stats() and edit the question with it? Not just the row count, we need it all

Comment: Also can you edit the question with the explain() of your query?

Comment: @mnemosyn find the output on this link http://s12.postimg.org/b0wq7l4e5/stack.png i don't have enough reputation to upload the image by editing here

Comment: The query itself, and `explain()` are also required - please edit the question and don't post a link to an image, but just copy & paste the text. Are you sure there's no other threads writing to the collection? Updates can also be a problem...